# Teamcity, build result, overview tab: any way to display failed test in order they ran?

Tags: teamcity

Teamcity, build result, overview tab: if any tests failed they diplays in alphabetical order ([as in a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqahV.jpg)).

Is there any way to order failed tests in order by that they ran (or by DateTime)?

Comment: What options do you get in that "Group by" dropdown box right above the list of tests?

Comment: @cascer1 It contains two options: "package/suit" (my case) and "do not group".

Option "do not group" does not get desired result.

Comment: What kind of ordering does "do not group" give you?

Comment: @cascer1 It just does not group failed tests by classes/packages. Flat list with alphabetical order.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Teamcity to help any further unfortunately. Though I am curious, why would you want to order your tests in the order they are executed? I believe unit tests are not executed in the same order they are written.

Comment: @cascer1 It's not unit tests but functional tests. So right order is important to easy interpretate this and localize bug. First test checks basic http response, so if it's not ok - all over tests will fail by design. Right ordering in overview tab could simplify this process.